# How to store subclass types and be able to instantiate a variable with the position of the list?

Tags: c#, list, types, subclass

I'm developing a game in C# on Unity that aims to learn basics in Python.

In my project I have created an abstract class **Execution** which defines the different types of executions in Python :

```cs
public abstract class Execution
{
    public enum ExecutionType
    {
        Affectation,
        Incrementation,
        Decrementation,
        Multiplier,
        Divisor,
        EntireDivisor,
        Modulo,
        IfStatement,
        ElseStatement,
        ForLoop,
        WhileLoop,
        Pass,  
    }
    
    public ExecutionType Type;

    public abstract string Representation();

    public Execution(ExecutionType type)
    {
        type = Type;
    }

    // Some others methods

}
```

And here is an example of a class that derives from **Execution** :

```cs
public class Pass : Execution
{
    public Pass() : base(ExecutionType.Pass) { }

    public override string Representation()
    {
        return IndentRepresentation($"<color=#eb8f34>pass</color>");
    }
}
```

All this allows me to create a random Python code generator in another script, so I started to think about an algorithm that allows to generate a Python code that works by instantiating for each line a class derived from the **Execution** class.

```cs
int randomIndex = 0; // Generated in the algorithm

List<Type> ExecutionsTypes = new List<Type>();
ExecutionsTypes.Add(typeof(Affectation)); // Error
ExecutionsTypes.Add(typeof(Pass));

Execution execution = (Execution)Activator.CreateInstance(ExecutionsTypes[randomIndex]); // Sometimes errors
```

My problem is that I want to store all the types of these classes in a list and be able to instantiate them by browsing the list but yet, some classes are generic classes (so I have an error in those places) but others have necessary arguments, and since the choice is random, I can't know how to put the necessary arguments.

Comment: Key details are missing from the question. It looks like you posted the parts you figured out but left out the parts that don't work, like the generics. I don't know if we even need all the details about the base class. Wouldn't the problem be exactly the same if these were all different types that didn't inherit from the base class?

Comment: Instead of storing the types in the list, getting a type, and trying to create an instance, perhaps you could create an instance of each class and put those in a list. Then instead of selecting a type, you select an instance of a class and just call its method. That could be a `List<Execution>`.

Comment: So I should create a parameterless constructor for each classes then call a `Set` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `Activator.CreateInstance(someType)` each type must have a parameterless constructor. You indicated that sometimes you get an error, so it's apparent that some of your classes don't. Even if they did that's a difficult design because later you might want to add a type without a default constructor and you won't be able to.

One approach is to create a list of instantiated classes instead of a list of types.

Instead of this:

```cs
List<Type> executionsTypes = new List<Type>();
executionsTypes.Add(typeof(Affectation));
executionsTypes.Add(typeof(Pass));
```

do this:

```cs
List<Execution> executions = new List<Execution>();
executions.Add(new Affectation()); 
executions.Add(new Pass());
```

Then instead of selecting a type from the list and having to instantiate it, you can select a class instance that's already been instantiated.

What if you don't want to re-use class instances and you need a new one each time? Then you could do this:

```cs
List<Func<Execution>> executions = new List<Func<Execution>>();
executions.Add(() => new Affectation()); 
executions.Add(() => new Pass());
executions.Add(() => new SomeTypeWithParameters("x", 1));
```

Then what you select from the list is a function that returns an `Execution`, and you call it to create a new instance.

```cs
Func<Execution> createExecutionFunction = // however you randomly select one
Execution execution = createExecutionFunction();
```